# JAXB separate episodes with annox customizations fails : SAXParseException2

Tags: jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, xmlcatalog, annox, jaxb-episode

I have 2 maven modules.

- First one contains only a xsd schema to generate base POJO classes.
- Second on contains a xsd schema that imports first one with a catalog file and generate new POJO classes.
  Both generation works.

Now, I add annotations to both xsd files with annox (Swagger annotations).
First module compilation succeeded but seconds module compilation fails with and exceptions :

```
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location : com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: jar:file:/C:/commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/Commons.xsd; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 36; compiler was unable to honor annox:annotate schemaBinding customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
```

***First module***

- 'Commons.xsd' :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.test.com/commons" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/commons" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:swagger="http://annox.dev.java.net/com.wordnik.swagger.annotations" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
      <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
          <annox:annotate target="class">
            <swagger:ApiModel value="BaseType" description="Description" />
          </annox:annotate>
        </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="field1" type="xs:integer"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
  ```
- 'pom.xml' :

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
              <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.2</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>0.8.3</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>generate</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <args>
                                  <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                              </args>
                              <plugins>
                                  <plugin>
                                      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                      <version>0.6.5</version>
                                  </plugin>
                                  <plugin>
                                      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                      <version>0.6.5</version>
                                  </plugin>
                              </plugins>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <dependencies>
                      <dependency>
                          <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                          <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                          <version>1.3.2</version>
                      </dependency>
                  </dependencies>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </project>
  ```

***Second module***

- 'Extension.xsd' :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.test.com/extension" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/extension" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" xmlns:swagger="http://annox.dev.java.net/com.wordnik.swagger.annotations" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.test.com/commons" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox" jaxb:version="2.1">
      <xs:import namespace="http://www.test.com/commons" schemaLocation="Commons.xsd" />
      <xs:complexType name="Extension">
          <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                  <annox:annotate target="class">
                      <swagger:ApiModel value="Extension" description="Description" />
                  </annox:annotate>
              </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexContent>
              <xs:extension base="c:BaseType">
                  <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="field2" type="xs:integer" />
                  </xs:sequence>
              </xs:extension>
          </xs:complexContent>
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
  ```
- 'pom.xml' :

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>extension</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>test</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>0.8.3</version>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>generate</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <configuration>
                              <args>
                                  <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                              </args>
                              <episodes>
                                  <episode>
                                      <groupId>test</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
                                  </episode>
                              </episodes>
                              <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.xml</catalog>
                              <plugins>
                                  <plugin>
                                      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                      <version>0.6.5</version>
                                  </plugin>
                                  <plugin>
                                      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                      <version>0.6.5</version>
                                  </plugin>
                              </plugins>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <dependencies>
                      <dependency>
                          <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                          <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                          <version>1.3.2</version>
                      </dependency>
                  </dependencies>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </project>
  ```
- 'catalog.xml' !

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
      <systemSuffix systemIdSuffix="Commons.xsd" uri="maven:test:commons!/Commons.xsd" />
  </catalog>
  ```

It's been days I'm trying to solve, without success, this error.

Comment: Could you please quote the solution, seems to be not accessible at the moment.

Comment: I found a possible solution here : https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/users/archive/2009-06/message/107

Comment: Ok, Alexey Valikov and me happen to be the same person. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug using annox and episodes.

I've solved the same issue through external binding (xjb file). In this way the schema is also clean.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
  jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
  version="2.1">

  <jaxb:globalBindings>
    <jaxb:serializable uid="12345"/> 
  </jaxb:globalBindings>


  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="domain1.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='SomeRootType']">
      <annox:annotate>
        <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="SomeRootType"/>
      </annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

this is the maven plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                <arg>-Xnamespace-prefix</arg>
                <arg>-nv</arg>
            </args>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
            <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/xjb</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <include>*.xjb</include>
            </bindingIncludes>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema/project/b</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*.xsd</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </schema>
                <schema>
                    <dependencyResource>
                        <groupId>com.project.a</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact.a</artifactId>
                        <resource>schema/a.xsd</resource>
                    </dependencyResource>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
            <episodes>
                <episode>
                    <groupId>com.project.a</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artifact.a</artifactId>
                </episode>
            </episodes>
            <debug>true</debug>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-namespace-prefix</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```